# In the modal popup how to identify selected item in content editor?

Tags: sitecore-client

I am trying to open a modal dialog from custom ribbon button and i would like to know which item was selected in the content editor within modal popup?

Is there a easy way to achieve this?

Note: I am not using SPEAK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to open a modal popup from Content Editor ribbon, it should be done using a Sitecore Command.

On your `Command` class itself, you can find the context item (Selected item), and pass it's Id in querystring of popup.

In the `Execute()` method of your Command class, your code will look like below.

```
    public override void Execute(CommandContext context)
    {
        if (context.Items.Length == 1)
        {
            // Get currently selected item in Content Editor tree
            Item currentItem = context.Items[0];

            // to read passed parameters, use context.Parameters["id"];

            // Continue your code for popup    

        }
    }
```